# Twitter API returning HTTP 220 for GET api/help/languages when using application-only authentication

Tags: python, twitter, oauth

I am using the [birdy](https://github.com/inueni/birdy) library and have an `AppClient` object successfully authenticated using application-only authentication. I can call `GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/application/rate_limit_status.json` successfully for example.

When trying to `GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/help/languages.json` with the same client object, the following error message is returned.

> Your credentials do not allow access to this resource.

I'm not sure why this might be as Twitter's [GET help/languages/](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/help/languages) documentation page has a rate limit for application-only authenticated clients, implying I should be able to fetch from this endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug on Twitter's side, as there's no good reason for the /help/ endpoints to require user context.

Comment: Twitter lists a rate limit for application-only clients for this endpoint so I'm wondering if it is something to do with my set up. I've tried with two different Twitter apps, so perhaps it is to do with the `birdy` library.

Comment: @JamesHiew no, I tried it with twurl and curl and can confirm what you are seeing. It is not happy with app-auth for some reason.